# Why is the image of an ImageView getting stretched?

Tags: android

I have the following layout:ö

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_gradient"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The 'gradient' image is a jpg with 400 x 400 pixels. My Screen size is 1920 x 1200. I set the `Gravity` of my `RelativeLayout` to be `center` and my `ImageView`'s height and width are defined to be `wrap_content`. I tried `scaleType="centerInside"`, `fitCenter` and so on and `centerInParent="true"` but nothing works. The `ImageView` always gets stretched to the screen size.

Why?

How can an `ImageView` with `wrap_content` Layout params take the whole screen when the content is 400 x 400. I dont get it.

**EDIT**

You can get the `Image` to center like that:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_gradient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />
```

**BUT**

The `ImageView` itself is still as big as the whole screen. Why is `wrap_content` ignored?

Comment: show code snippet of setting image in imageView

Comment: ehm... i posted the code for setting the image in imageview. its in the layout file. 'android:background="@drawable/gradient'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep you scaleType attribute in there when changing it to `src`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_gradient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blue"
    android:contentDescription="imageview_description"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

or just use

```
android:scaleType="center" />
```

> Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling. From XML, use this syntax: android:scaleType="center".

[android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

edit:

I have just reduced my image size to demonstrate that it works, it should not resize it to be greater than your 400px.

[image: portrait]  [image: landscape]

Comment: the centering now is working. but as i edited in my post, the Layout size of the ImageView is still as big as the screen size. So wrap_content gets totally ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Use src instead of background

```
android:src="@drawable/gradient"
```

src has the features of fitCenter etc. Background will always stretch

Comment: doesnt change anything.

Comment: that's because of scaleType I think, try remove it and use src.

Comment: yes it does indeed. but the wrap_content is still ignored. the image gets centered but the layout of the ImageView still is as big as the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height to 400px, if you want to display the image at it's true resolution without stretching. 
You can also set `scaleType="center"` to apply no scaling to the original image and `centerInParent="true"` to position the ImageView in the center of the RelativeLayout.
Also do not forget to set the ImageView image with `src="@drawable/yourdrawable"`

I would not recommend setting the image width and height to a static pixel amount because it can look weird on different devices.

Things you can read for more info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Yes i dont want to set it with true pixels because it has to work relatively to the screen size. scaleType="center" and centerInParent="true" does not change anything. it is always stretched.

Answer (score 0):

android:scaleType is just working in src
so when you want you scale picture,you should not use background but src attribute

Comment: you can try set android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` instead of using `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.